# Expo account login timeout

Tags: react-native, proxy, expo

I can't login to my expo account.

In CMD commands:

```
C:\Users\Mohammad>expo login
? Username/Email Address: mohammadss
? Password: [hidden]
[13:01:41] connect ETIMEDOUT 35.202.142.166:443
[13:01:41] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

I'm running lantern VPN, because I'm from Iran and it necessary. What should I do now?

I have tried to set proxy for my system, but noting changed.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: any one who found a solution